# I want to delete a document using ObjectID in mongodb using express.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am getting this error
Error: Argument passed in must be a single string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

```
app.post("/delete", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.deleteCheckbox);
  Item.findByIdAndDelete(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.deleteCheckbox), function(err){
    if(!err){
      console.log("Successfully deleted");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});
```

please help me

Comment: what value are you passing as a deleteCheckbox?

Comment: new ObjectID("string");

Comment: I am passing corresponding _id of document